# it is not possible to do xml demarshalling using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to parse XML into a Java object, but an error comes out. I have an xml file

```
<ED807 xmlns="urn:cbr-ru:ed:v2.0" EDDate="2023-05-13">
    <BICDirectoryEntry BIC="041280103">
        <ParticipantInfo NameP="SAMAT" CntrCd="RU" Rgn="12" Ind="414056" Tnp="г"
                         Adr="FHD" DateIn="2010-06-08" ParticipantStatus="PSAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
        <Accounts CK="99" AccountCBRBIC="041280002" DateIn="2013-01-09" AccountStatus="ACAC"/>
    </BICDirectoryEntry>

    <BICDirectoryEntry BIC="040147000">
        <ParticipantInfo NameP="РКЦ БИЙСК"  Tnp="г" Adr="ул. Владимира Ленина, 127"
                         DateIn="1994-01-20" ParticipantStatus="PSAC"/>
    </BICDirectoryEntry>

</ED807>
```

I use classes
teg ED807

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "ED807", namespace = "urn:cbr-ru:ed:v2.0")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ED807 {


    private String edDate;
    private BICDirectoryEntry[] bicDirectoryEntries;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "EDDate")
    public String getEdDate() {
        return edDate;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "BICDirectoryEntry")
    public BICDirectoryEntry[] getBicDirectoryEntries() {
        return bicDirectoryEntries;
    }
}
```

teg BICDirectoryEntry

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BICDirectoryEntry")
@Getter
@Setter
public class BICDirectoryEntry {
    @XmlElement(name = "ParticipantInfo")
    private ParticipantInfo participantInfo;

    @XmlElement(name = "Accounts")
    private Accounts[] accountList;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "BIC")
    private String bic;

}
```

teg ParticipantInfo

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ParticipantInfo")
public class ParticipantInfo {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "NameP", required = true)
    private String nameP;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "CntrCd", required = true)
    private String cntrCd;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "RegN")
    private String regN;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Tnp")
    private String tnp;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Nnp", required = true)
    private String nnp;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Adr")
    private String adr;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "PtType")
    private String ptType;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ParticipantStatus")
    private String participantStatus;

}
```

and teg Accounts

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Accounts")
@XmlRootElement
public class Accounts {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Account", required = true)
    private String accountNumber;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "RegulationAccountType")
    private String regulationAccountType;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DateIn")
    private String dateIn;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "DateOut")
    private String dateOut;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "AccountStatus")
    private String accountStatus;
}
```

**Но при тестирование выходит это:**

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, where is the error in the annotations

I tried to put an annotation *@XmlElementWrapper* above the nested tags, but it also gave an error